# ASP.NET log requests to Amazon S3 objects

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3, umbraco

I've put some objects in an S3 bucket and I want to log everytime a client makes a request to one of those objects.

I'm using Umbraco 4.8 as my back-end with some custom code running.

The solutions I've come up with:

1. Set the link to an ASP page that pulls the object from S3 and sends it back as the response. The problem I see there is then the client has to wait for ASP to load the file before it can begin downloading the file.
2. Set the link to an ASP page that logs the request and returns a Response.Redirect to the S3 object. To me this seems like an unnecessary redirect and the client might cache that redirect and not hit my server the next time they access that object.

Does anyone have any other solutions or thoughts on how to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jquery and google analytics.  Add a class to each link that you want to track and then use jquery to manipulate the onclick event to something like:

```
<a href="[link]" onclick="__gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 's3-Bucket-Request', 's3-actual-bucket-name', 'current-page']);">link text</a>
```

Replacing the three variables appropriately ('s3-Bucket-Request', 's3-actual-bucket-name', 'current-page').  If you then put the jquery at the head of each page you have a reusable function.

start:

```
<a href="[link]" class="ga">link text</a>
```

jquery:

```
$('.ga').attr("onclick", "__gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 's3-Bucket-Request', 's3-actual-bucket-name', 'current-page']);");
```

end:

```
<a href="[link]" class="ga" onclick="__gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 's3-Bucket-Request', 's3-actual-bucket-name', 'current-page']);">link text</a>
```

Comment: That can become a problem when the link is to a video on S3: <video src="S3 Bucket Link"></video

Comment: @HJ05 You need to replace the three variables appropriately ('s3-Bucket-Request', 's3-actual-bucket-name', 'current-page') - depending on what you are tracking in Google Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how accurate you need this to be, you could also do it client side. Using jQuery, etc, add a click handler to `a href` tags that makes an ajax request to a controller, logging the activity.

Comment: I thought of that, and that is a possibility, but some of the links might not be in my control.